# Pass date data from a Picker to another view controller in Swift

Tags: swift, segue, picker

I want to be able to choose a time via a picker on one view and pass that data onto another view.

I am able to do this as a string but how do I pass the time data in order to do calculation.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
            let destinationController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
           
            destinationController.timeLabelTextOut = timeLabel.text!
            
        }
    }

    @IBAction func dayFinishTimePicker(_ sender: Any) {
       
        let timeformat = DateFormatter()
               timeformat.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let finishTime = timeformat.string(from: dayFinishTimePicker.date)
        
        timeLabel.text = finishTime
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the date itself and format it there to get the time inside `viewDidLoad` of the next vc

```
destinationController.dateSent = dayFinishTimePicker.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i would declare `finishTime` var outside the function and make it a var:

```
var finishTime = Date()
```

In `SecondViewController` i would create a var `fTime` like that:

```
var fTime = Date()
```

Then i would write in `prepare` func:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationController.fTime! = self.finishTime
        destinationController.timeLabelTextOut = timeLabel.text!
        
    }
}
```

And the `@IBAction` function goes like that:

```
 @IBAction func dayFinishTimePicker(_ sender: Any) {
   
    let timeformat = DateFormatter()
           timeformat.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    self.finishTime = dayFinishTimePicker.date
    
    timeLabel.text = timeformat.string(from: dayFinishTimePicker.date)
  
}
```

Comment: Also if `timeLabelTextOut ` from `SecondViewController `  is a label be careful to set its text in `viewDidLoad()` in the `SecondViewController ` , because the label is not instantiated yet